# Fixed div that moves vertically at 2x scrollspeed when scrolling

Tags: scroll, fixed

I would like to make a `div` move down on scroll but at a faster rate (i.e. if the user scrolls 200px down the `div` will smoothly scroll 400px down.)
Basically a fixed `div` that moves up and down at 2x (maybe less) rate of the scroll speed

I have searched a lot for an answer but no luck so I hope one of you bright minds can help me.

If you need me to be more specific I can make a video or an illustration that clarifies what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to do a *parallax scrolling* effect. There are lots of js libraries that can do this, one of them is: [Stellar.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/)

Nike also made a temporary site ([Better World](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmGDwm5-a80)) that had this effect.